# terraform script to create mysql schema and load data

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform

I created the RDS Aurora database in AWS management console. I have the sql script on mysql schema and insert statement.

I created the terraform script on the database creation, and next is to use terraform to create mysql schema and load data. My question is do I use terraform script to create mysql schema and load data? I am not clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use terraform to create your mysql schema, and load data, by leveraging terraform provisioniner: https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html

For example, you can execute remote scripts with remote-exec. This

You should be aware that terraform core capabilities is to provision infrastructure. Configuring and managing services is better achieved with specialized tools.